# Find out where a SVN tag came from (SVNkit)

Tags: java, svn, tagging, svnkit

We have a standard SVN project structure with

```
/trunk
/branches
/tags
```

as subdirectories. Our build server makes builds on the trunk and on different branches. At the end of the build, the used revision of the trunk or branch is tagged in the `tags` directory.

It is easy to read all SVN revisions of a project with SVNkit from Java. Now, for the tagging revisions, I would like to find out *where the tag came from*, i.e. if the trunk was tagged, or if a branch was tagged.

Is this possible?

I went through the methods of `SVNLogEntry` but could not find the relevant information.

Comment: If I correctly remember you have to go via SVNLogEntryPath which contains the information if a path has been copied or not. Based on that you can identify it. See https://github.com/khmarbaise/supose/blob/master/supose-core/src/main/java/com/soebes/supose/core/scan/ScanRepository.java#L206